# Open debian package with Java

Tags: java, debian, unpack, deb

Are there any libraries in Java for unpacking a .deb (debian) archive? Unfortunately I Couldn't find anything useful out there yet. Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean just opening the archive to examine it's contents or actually deploy the archive?

Comment: The user wrote "... for unpacking a .deb ..." so he probably means extraction.

Comment: I want to unpack and deploy the archive to a temporary folder. So, if the .deb archive contains files/folders X,Y,Z I want to extract X,Y,Z to a temporary folder, say "T" and be able to create a "new File(T, X)".

Answer (score 3):

If you by unpacking mean extracting the files, it should be possible with [Apache Commons Compress](http://commons.apache.org/compress/). A .deb file is "[implemented as an ar archive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deb_%28file_format%29#Implementation)" and Commons Compress is able to uncompress ar archives.

Comment: Thanks, I will definitely try Apache Commons Compress... Didn't notice the "ar archive" part.

Comment: Notice that the top-level `ar` archive will in turn contain two `tar` archives, but apparently ACC should cope with that, too.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so as suggested I've used apache commons compress and here's a method that does the trick. Downladed it from the maven repo: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-compress/1.2.

```
/**
 * Unpack a deb archive provided as an input file, to an output directory.
 * <p>
 * 
 * @param inputDeb      the input deb file.
 * @param outputDir     the output directory.
 * @throws IOException 
 * @throws ArchiveException 
 * 
 * @returns A {@link List} of all the unpacked files.
 * 
 */
private static List<File> unpack(final File inputDeb, final File outputDir) throws IOException, ArchiveException {

    LOG.info(String.format("Unzipping deb file %s.", deb.getAbsoluteFile()));
    LOG.info(String.format("Into dir %s.", outDir.getAbsoluteFile()));

    final List<File> unpackedFiles = new LinkedList<File>();
    final InputStream is = new FileInputStream(inputDeb); 
    final ArArchiveInputStream debInputStream = (ArArchiveInputStream) new ArchiveStreamFactory().createArchiveInputStream("ar", is);
    ArArchiveEntry entry = null; 
    while ((entry = (ArArchiveEntry)debInputStream.getNextEntry()) != null) {
        LOG.info("Read entry");
        final File outputFile = new File(outputDir, entry.getName());
        final OutputStream outputFileStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile); 
        IOUtils.copy(debInputStream, outputFileStream);
        outputFileStream.close();
        unpackedFiles.add(outputFile);
    }
    debInputStream.close(); 
    return unpackedFiles;
}
```

Comment: I have a correction to the above source code. Please note that the "entry" variable may represent a directory. In this case, please add the check if (entry.isDirectory()) and make sure you create the directory needed.